# Android emulator qemu take about 3GB of memory PC runs very slow

Tags: 18.04, qemu, emulation, android-emulator

I installed [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro) on an Ubuntu 18.04 system to learn [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/).  That PC has 8 GB RAM and an [Intel Core i3-6006U 2.0GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91157/intel-core-i3-6006u-processor-3m-cache-2-00-ghz.html) CPU.

When I launch the emulator, the PC becomes very slow, & **qemu takes about 3GB**.

[image]

How may I fix that, since I can't even work in Android Studio and things become very difficult.

Comment: 1) Which release number of Andorid Studio and 2) Flutter did you install? 3) Is VM acceleration https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration configured? 4) Does your ASUS machine have a GPU or are you relying on the Intel® HD Graphics 520 of the i3 CPU? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

As [noted by one dev](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-run-virtual-machines-on-i3-without-any-lags-or-issues), the i3 CPU "isn’t the best processor to run virtual machines". Another dev there said "An i3 laptop grade processor is only meant to browse web and edit docs and PDFs" and "You are talking about one of the worst processors on the market".

This chart shows the [ranking of that CPU](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core%20i3-6006U%20%40%202.00GHz&id=2912) compared to others.

Using qemu is the least worst way to set up Android Studio on that machine; you may have done all you can with the limits of your hardware.

Comment: Ok, I'll give up until buying new computer , i5 or i7. thanks

Comment: in fact I have decided to learn flutter using web chrome until changing my laptop, i'll just click on the up arrow for the moment